# c++ casting string to LPCWSTR in parameter

Tags: c++, string, casting, lpcwstr

I can see that i can cast a string type to LPCWSTR in a parameter like this:

```
myfunc(L"mystring");
```

But suppose i want to pass a string as a variable this time, how would i cast it with ease like above (not converting the variable):

```
string myStringVar = "mystring";
myfunc(myStringVar);
```

I tried a few things like:

```
myfunc(L{mystringvar});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a wide string you need a `std::wstring`.  You could use it like

```
std::wstring myStringVar = L"mystring";
myfunc(myStringVar.c_str());
```